# Handling multiple API calls of a single API call

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

With my team we are trying to implement a command for a really common operation for the business logic but I'm having issues handling its implementation.
Basically:

1. We have to retrieve an **array of objects** (GET).
2. For each of that objects we have to retrieve (GET) another **object inside its parent**.
3. For each of that sub-objects (childs) we have to **check a condition** and if it is the wanted condition we retrieve the child, otherwise we pass null.

**Q:** How do I handle **multiple API calls that depends from a single API call** without getting outside the CY chain?

This is my current implementation (doesn't works but kinda explains the wanted logic)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('myCommand', (sumCriteria: Function, anotherCriteria: Function) => {
    // I only retrieve parents with certain criteria
    return cy.request('GET', parentsUrl).its('body').then(parentObjects => {
        return parentObjects.filter(parent => parent.childs.length && parent.childs.find(sumCriteria))
    }).then(filteredParents => {
        filteredParents.forEach(parent => {
            // For each parent I retrieve a single child
            const targetChildId = parent.childs.find(sumCriteria).id;
            // For each single child I retrieve its data and evaluate if it has the needed criteria
            cy.request('GET', `${childsUrl}/${targetChildId}`)
                .its('body')
                .then(property => anotherCriteria(property))
        })
    });
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've heard of parent objects, but never father objects.  I wonder if it's a linguistic variance.

Comment: I was just thinking in spanish while writing the scenario. I'm gonna edit it

Comment: You can use whatever variable naming fits the problem domain best, it will not cause an issue.

Comment: @GonzaloDiazAilan No worries! I kind of guessed it was something like that. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have the correct pattern, but instead of returning results, put them on the queue.

Cypress does two things to make this work

- in a custom command, it waits for any asynchronous commands to resolve
- it returns whatever is on the queue at the last evaluation

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('myCommand', (sumCriteria, anotherCriteria) => {

  cy.request('GET', fathersUrl)
    .its('body')
    .then(fatherObjects => {

      const filteredFathers  = fatherObjects.filter(father => {
        return father.childs.find(sumCriteria)
      });

      const results = []
      filteredFathers.forEach(father => { 
        cy.request('GET', father)              // waits for all these to resove
          .its('body')
          .then(property => anotherCriteria(property))   
      })

      cy.then(() => results)                   // returns this last queued command
  })
})
```

A reproducible example:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('myCommand', (sumCriteria, anotherCriteria) => {

  const fathersUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'

  cy.request('GET', fathersUrl)
    .then(() => {

      // simulated url extraction
      const filteredFathers = [
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2', 
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3'
      ]

      const results = []
      filteredFathers.forEach(father => { 
        cy.request('GET', father)
          .then(res => {
            results.push(res.body.id)
          })
      });

      cy.then(() => results)
  });
})

cy.myCommand()
  .should('deep.eq', [2,3])             // ✅ passes
```